# Should I choose “unlimited” (maxmemory 0), to be on the safe side? Redis Server

Tags: caching, server, redis

hi i am using 4GB VPS Hosing Plan and my wordpress dataset size is 4.7GB. how much redis maxmemory limit is good for me based on my 4gb vps hosting plan

right now iam using the following redis config

maxmemory 256mb

maxmemory-policy allkeys-lru

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not set it to unlimited. This setting is actually really helpful to prevent your Redis instance from crashing upon full memory. The documentation says this:

> Set an explicit maxmemory option limit in your instance to make sure that it will report errors instead of failing when the system memory limit is near to be reached. Note that maxmemory should be set by calculating the overhead for Redis, other than data, and the fragmentation overhead. So if you think you have 10 GB of free memory, set it to 8 or 9.